# Creating disk partitions in fedora 22

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, fedora-22

I have only one single partition on a 500gb hard disk. I want to partition it and create some unused free space so that I can install windows in that free space.

I am currently running fedora 22. Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: this has to be a dupe

Answer (score 0):

i believe **gparted** will help you out!

```
dnf install gparted
```

you can also get a live version (around 250MB) but running directy within ur system will just work fine, no worries